# How can I do update action in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm building contact app with react redux. Here, the add and remove functions work normally. But there is a problem in the editing part. When you click on the update button of a contact, you will be directed to that page, all information will be filled in appropriate inputs. But I encounter an error in the update part. How can I fix my mistake?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { UpdateContact } from '../redux/actions/Actions'

const UpdateContactPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const contacts = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.contacts)
  const updatedBlog = contacts.find((blog) => blog.id === id)

  const [a, setA] = useState(updatedBlog)

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    id: a.id,
    userName: a.userName,
    surname: a.surname,
    image: a.image
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const updateContactForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // dispatch(UpdateContact(user))
    console.log(user);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <form onSubmit={updateContactForm}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <input type="text" name='userName' className="form-control" placeholder='username' onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={a.userName} />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <input type="text" name='image' className="form-control" placeholder='img' onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={a.image} />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <input type="text" name='surname' className="form-control" placeholder='surname' onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={a.surname} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default UpdateContactPage
```

```js
const initialState = {
    contacts: localStorage.getItem('Contacts') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Contacts')) : []
}

export const AppReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_CONTACT":
            return {
                ...state,
                contacts: [...state.contacts, action.payload]
            }
        case "UPDATE_CONTACT":
            const updatedContact = action.payload;
            const updatedContacts = state.contacts.map((contact) => {
                if (contact.id === updatedContact.id) {
                    return updatedContact
                }
                return contact
            })
            return updatedContacts
        case "REMOVE_CONTACT":
            return {
                ...state,
                contacts: state.contacts.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload)
            }
        case "REMOVE_ALL_CONTACTS":
            return {
                ...state,
                contacts: []
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const AddContact = (user) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_CONTACT',
        payload: user
    }
}

export const DeleteContact = (id) => {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_CONTACT',
        payload: id
    }
}

export const UpdateContact = (id) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_CONTACT',
        payload: id
    }
}

export const RemoveAll = () => {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_ALL_CONTACTS',
    }
}
```

Comment: "But I encounter an error in the update part." <- what is the error you encounter?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Please [edit] to clarify what the problem is. If there's an error, please include the complete error message, any accompanying code stacktrace, any reproduction steps, any any debugging steps you've already taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `UPDATE_CONTACT` case of your reducer you are using the payload as if it is a user:

```
const updatedContact = action.payload;
```

but your UpdateContact function has an id for its payload:

```
export const UpdateContact = (id) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_CONTACT',
        payload: id
    }
}
```

Comment: The payload ***is*** a user, from `dispatch(UpdateContact(user))`. It's the same as `action.payload.id`, or "`user.id`". Only the argument passed to the `UpdateContact` is "misnamed", it should be `const UpdateContact = contact => ({ type: ...., payload: contact })` to make things more clear. I don't think your answer resolves any issue OP has.